# Regarding Capture in Stata

Tags: append, stata

I have code that I mostly took from here (bottom column): http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/append_many_files.htm

```
clear
file open myfile9 using C:\Users\RNCZF01\Documents\Cameron-Fen\Economics-Projects\Neighborhood-Project\list.csv, read
file read myfile9 line
insheet using `line', comma

save `line'.dta, replace
save master_data.dta, replace

drop _all

file read myfile9 line
while r(eof)==0 {
    capture insheet using `line', comma
    if _rc!=0 {
        insheet using `line', comma
        save `line'.dta, replace
        append using master_data.dta, force
        save master_data.dta, replace
    }
    drop _all
    file read myfile9 line
}
```

Originally I had `insheet using line', comma` (I removed the back tick before the line because it was interfering with formatting).  But the problem was that some of my sheets I was attempting to read were blank and so Stata would close.  Thus I changed that to this:

```
capture insheet using `line', comma
    if _rc!=0 {
        insheet using `line', comma
```

However this closes after only reading the first document (and exits in the while loop before the first iteration of the while loop (second document) is done).  My thought was that macros may disappear when they are used but I have no idea.

Comment: If you have Stata 13 or 14, you should use `import delimited` rather than `insheet`. The new command is much more flexible.

Comment: Also, you want `if _rc == 0` because this indicates that no error occurred during the `insheet`.

Comment: @lmp is right in recommending `import delimited`. Using macros does not cause them to disappear. Otherwise, why not use your operating system to tell which files are empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your loop is closing is because you want

```
if _rc==0
```

for the inner loop. I am guessing your first file is not found, insheet throws up an error, and you are triggering the if _rc!=0 condition. Then the loop tries to run insheet without the capture and errors out. Another way of diagnosing this would be to run

```
set trace on
```

which I have found helpful in these sort of situations.

P.S. Not sure of the etiquette, but credit for this answer goes to lmo. I just thought it was worth writing up as an answer rather than a comment.